# Run cspell with dictionaries using npx

Tags: npx, hunspell

Can I run cspell check with dictionary/ies?

I have this command and it works:

```
npx cspell "**" --config C:\Users\Anonymous\source\repos\project\.config\.cspell.json
```

but what I want is to add in my cspell.json following:

```
{
    "dictionaries": [
        "en-us",
        "en-gb",
        "de-de", // <- added new dictionary
        ...
  ],
    "import": ["@cspell/dict-de-de/cspell-ext.json"]
}
```

Here are commands which use npm, but I want to locally use npx to get dictionary and in cspell.json import dictionary and perform spell check by selected dictionary.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cspell/dict-de-de

Is it possible to run this with npx (**I can't use npm**)?